# Tautomerism in 3,5‐dimethyl‐4H‐pyrazole

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

How would tautomerism take place in 3,5‐dimethyl‐4H‐pyrazole?

[image: 3,5‐dimethyl‐4H‐pyrazole]

I am aware of nitro–aci nitro and keto–enol, but I haven't seen such a compound before. I recognize that a hydrazone formation was done but nothing more. From what I was able to reason, an alkadiene is formed but that is unstable, so tautomerism shouldn't be possible. How does this compound show tautomerism?

Comment: Replace the N’s with O’s and remove the single bond between them. Do you know how to draw the tautomer of *that*? Well yes you do, so draw it. Then replace the O’s with N’s and add the single bond back.

Comment: You might want to try tautomerism with a simpler, similar compound first eg pyrrole, then move on to making the tautomers for this compound.

Answer (score 5):

You are lucky, because not only the pyrazole motif, but the complete structure drawn by you is part of the [Tautobase](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035) database

[image]

with a preference for the second structure drawn.

By the way, the values of this database are accessible to the public on [GitHub](https://github.com/WahlOya/Tautobase), and since January 2020 implemented as (equally [sub]structure) searchable data file within [DataWarrior](http://openmolecules.org/datawarrior/index.html).  Thus, you may train your chemical eye on 1680 tautomers.

*Tautobase: An Open Tautomer Database*, Wahl, O.; Sanders, T. *J. Chem. Inf. Model.* 2020, **60**,1085-1089; [doi 10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035)